# What is the meaning of __total__ dunder attribute in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

In newly released Python 3.8 there is a new type annotation [`typing.TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict). Its documentation mentions that

> The type info for introspection can be accessed via `Point2D.__annotations__` and `Point2D.__total__`. [....]

While `__annotations__` is well-known, having been introduced in [PEP 3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/), I cannot find any information on `__total__`. Could anyone explain its meaning and if possible linking to authoritative sources?

Comment: Typical. 99% of `typing` internals isn't documented, and the part that is is documented poorly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am guessing that the `__total__` field signifies whether instances must be complete (the default) or not (all fields optional). I started my search at [PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#totality), which introduced `TypedDict` and describes totality as such. It used a `total` argument, which it would make sense to rename dunder-style for the `class`  syntax. However, I did not find when such a renaming took place.

Looking into MyPy, which is the actual type checker that cares about these annotations, there is [similar documentation on `TypedDict` and totality](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#totality), but again no reference to the dunder syntax. Digging into its implementation led to more confusion, as [`TypedDictType` in types.py](https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/8990ebdb884ed2d5b5dcb1dac5d8a8407358ef21/mypy/types.py#L1348) doesn't have a total field, but separate `items` and `required_keys`. Totality would imply that `items.keys()==required_keys` but the implementation makes different assumptions, such as `can_be_false` relying on `items` alone. `total=False` should in principle mean `required_keys` is empty.

The CPython source for [_TypedDictMeta](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8252c52e57283515ace5d4251584255dc5c60eb5/Lib/typing.py#L1698) at least reveals that the `total` argument and `__total__` dunder are one and the same, although the source describes `TypedDict` itself as "may be added soon".

Comment: Accepting this for now - if not anything else, maybe it will make others more willing to come forward and refute your answer :D

Comment: I personally suspect the `can_be_false` thing is a MyPy bug, possibly related to not having planned to have optional fields from the start.

Answer (score 3):

`TypedDict` was accepted in Python 3.8 via [PEP 589](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#totality). From Python, it appears `__total__` is a boolean flag set to `True` by default:

```
tot = TypedDict.__total__
print(type(tot))
print(tot)

# <class 'bool'>
# True
```

As mentioned in other posts, details on this method are limited in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict), but @Yann Vernier's link to the [CPython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8252c52e57283515ace5d4251584255dc5c60eb5/Lib/typing.py#L1698-L1718) strongly suggests `__total__` is related to the new `total` keyword [introduced in Python 3.8](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1175105764823719942):

```
# cypthon/typing.py

class _TypedDictMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, ns, total=True):
        """Create new typed dict class object.
        ...
        """
        ...
        if not hasattr(tp_dict, '__total__'):
            tp_dict.__total__ = total
        ...
```

How does it work?

*Synopsis*: by default, all keys are required when instantiating a defined `TypedDict`.  `total=False` overrides this restriction and allows optional keys.  See the following demonstration.

**Given**

A test directory tree:

[image]

**Code**

Files in the test directory:

```
# rgb_bad.py

from typing import TypedDict


class Color(TypedDict):
    r: int
    g: int
    b: int
    a: float


blue = Color(r=0, g=0, b=255)                     # missing "a"
```

```
# rgb_good.py

from typing import TypedDict


class Color(TypedDict, total=False):
    r: int
    g: int
    b: int
    a: float


blue = Color(r=0, g=0, b=255)                     # missing "a"
```

**Demo**

If a key is missing, mypy will complain at the commandline:

```
> mypy code/rgb_bad.py
code\rgb_bad.py:11: error: Key 'a' missing for TypedDict "Color"
...
```

Setting `total=False` permits optional keys:

```
> mypy code/rgb_good.py
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

**See Also**

- [Tweet](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/1175105764823719942) by R. Hettinger demonstating totality
- PEP [section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0589/#totality) on totality in PEP 589
- Article [Section](https://realpython.com/python38-new-features/#more-precise-types) on types and `TypedDict` in Python 3.8 by Real Python
- [`typing-extensions` package](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) to use `TypedDict` in Python 3.5, 3.6